# Why don't I see ads on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Alright I understand Ads are annoying at times, but its been a while since I am not seeing any ads on YouTube. Well all I see is a white background with the **Skip Ads** Button and a **Timer** kind of thing at the bottom-left. Also, I am not using YouTube Premium.

This is all that I see before the actual video.

[image: No ads]

So does anyone have an idea about this? I'm just curious to know why am I not seeing any ads.

Comment: Could be a browser issue? Maybe try in a incognito window or some other browser. Are there any errors on the dev console?

Comment: Nope.. Facing the same problem on other browsers as well and incognito also doesn't help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but it sounds like it might be a problem with YouTube. If it is then you can get something like CCleaner which clears all the cache and things that need to be cleared and that can help a lot of the times.

If you put code in the HTML that might be affecting it, or maybe the country region is making it like that. There's also a chance that it is your account. These are all just small steps that I'm not sure if it will fix it but will help you get a better gauge on the issue. And maybe restart your computer if you did everything and it's still not showing ads correctly.

Comment: Clearing Cache Worked !!

Comment: Glad I could help :D